# PHP Echo'd in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP script which echos in a div, which had another div inside of it. I am stumped, and I want to know how to make the second div seperate from the first one, so that one will be on one side and the other on the other side.

**Here's the PHP**

```
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  if(!empty($row['first_name'])) {
      echo '<div class="vpside">';
      echo '<p>Name:' . $row['first_name'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender: ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  if(!empty($row['post'])) {
      echo '<p class="vpside1">Post:</p><p class="viewpost1">' . $row['post'] . '</p>';
    }
    }
  echo '</div>';
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
.vpside {
    height:100%;
    width:12%;
    display:block;
    border-right:5px solid white;
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
    border-top:5px solid white;
}

.vpside1 {
    width:10%;
    border-right:5px solid white;
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
    border-top:5px solid white;
}

.viewpost {
    margin-bottom:25px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
}

p.viewpost {
    background-color: #000;
}

.viewpost1 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    }
```

Comment: You could end up with invalid HTML here. For example if $row['first_name'] is empty but $row['gender'] is not, you'll have an extra closing tag.

Comment: @jd182 They're going to be empty

Comment: @user2544765 That's what @jd182 is trying to say. If `$row['first_name']` or `$row['gender']` are going to be empty then you will have invalid HTML code being `echo'd` from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just end the first div before you define the other div to separate them.  For example:

```
<?php
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  echo '</div>'; //Bottom line moved here
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  if(!empty($row['first_name'])) {
      echo '<div class="vpside">';
      echo '<p>Name:' . $row['first_name'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender: ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  if(!empty($row['post'])) {
      echo '<p class="vpside1">Post:</p><p class="viewpost1">' . $row['post'] . '</p>';
    }
    }
?>
```

Or if you wanted to keep the `<p>` inside the one div:

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  if(!empty($row['first_name'])) {
      echo '<div class="vpside">';
      echo '<p>Name:' . $row['first_name'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender: ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  if(!empty($row['post'])) {
      echo '<p class="vpside1">Post:</p><p class="viewpost1">' . $row['post'] . '</p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Then, if you want them to be side by side, add `display: inline-block` to each div:

```
.vpside {
    height:100%;
    width:12%;
    display: inline-block; /*changed from display: block*/
    border-right:5px solid white;
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
    border-top:5px solid white;
}

.vpside1 {
    width:10%;
    border-right:5px solid white;
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
    border-top:5px solid white;
}

.viewpost {
    margin-bottom:25px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
}

p.viewpost {
    background-color: #000;
}

.viewpost1 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```